# Insert a new row for each missing date for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with about 18 columns of dates with data points and about 3k rows.

I'm trying to make sure that all the rows have the same dates. If a date is missing, I want a new row inserted with the missing date and #N/A next to it. Some of the columns have skipped a few days compared to previous columns.

How can I tweak this macro I found, for multiple columns?

```vb
Sub insertMissingDate()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wks.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    'Work bottom up since we are inserting new rows
    For i = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        curcell = wks.Cells(i, 3).Value
        prevcell = wks.Cells(i - 1, 3).Value

        'Using a loop here allows us to bridge a gap of multiple missing dates
        Do Until curcell - 1 = prevcell Or curcell = prevcell
            'Insert new row
            wks.Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown

            'Insert missing date into new row
            curcell = wks.Cells(i + 1, 3) - 1
            wks.Cells(i, 3).Value = curcell
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

This shows the problem where the dates are misaligned.

[image: Cells that are missing in row]

This shows a fixed row, with cells shifted down.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhg9D.png]

Comment: Can you edit to include a screenshot of your data - perhaps showing examples of what you have and what you'd like after code is finished

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Just added screenshots to make it easier.

Comment: Okay - that's a still a little hard to see what you're talking about because of having to flip back and forth between links, but I think I understand now. You don't really want a new row inserted - you want to shift the data in two columns down - and replace the cells in the current row's two columns with the matching date and #NA.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertMissingDate()
    Const FIRST_ROW     As Integer = 2

    Const COMPARE_COL   As Integer = 3
    Const COL1          As String = "C"
    Const COL2          As String = "D"

    Dim wks             As Worksheet
    Dim strRange        As String
    Dim lastRow         As Long
    Dim i               As Long

    Dim curCell         As Date
    Dim prevCell        As Date

    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")


    lastRow = wks.Range(COL1 & FIRST_ROW).End(xlDown).Row

    'Work bottom up since we are inserting new rows
    For i = FIRST_ROW To lastRow

        curCell = wks.Cells(i, COMPARE_COL).Value
        prevCell = wks.Cells(i, COMPARE_COL - 2).Value

        If curCell <> prevCell Then
            strRange = COL1 & i & ":" & COL2 & i
            Range(strRange).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            wks.Cells(i, COMPARE_COL).Value = prevCell
            wks.Cells(i, COMPARE_COL + 1).Value = "#N/A"
        End If
    Next i

    Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```